# JSF-Testing with embedded TomEE: Manipulate injected object

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, testing, containers, apache-tomee

I have a JSF-Project with one class called **Label** and one xhtml-page, called **label.xhtml**. In **label.xhtml** the method **Label.getValue()** is called via injection. The test **LabelTest** runs a embedded container and in a test method **label.xhtml** is requested and the body content will be checked. So far everything is fine, but I would like to change the value of the attribute **Label.value** in my test so the test can assert his own set value and not the value of the Postconstruct-method of class **Label**.

I put a breakpoint in the constructor of class **Label**. So I can see the stacktrace and I read the code of many of these methods. Maybe it is possible to change the produces class, so I can put there my own **AbstractProducer** in some way?

[Stacktrace Label constructor](https://github.com/feidner/stackoverflow-label/blob/master/stacktrace.png)

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/feidner/stackoverflow-label) or scroll down.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Label {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void fillValue() {
        setValue("HELLO");
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.apache.tomee.embedded.EmbeddedTomEEContainer;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class LabelTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        Map<Object, Object> properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put(EJBContainer.PROVIDER, EmbeddedTomEEContainer.class);
        properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File[]{new File("src/main/webapp/")});
        properties.put(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "hfe");
        System.setProperty("tomee.webapp.externalRepositories", "build/classes/main,build/classes/test");

        EmbeddedTomEEContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void requestHtmlPage_ThenBodyContainsPostConstructValue() {
        assertEquals("HELLO", getBodyValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void manipulateInjectedObjectAndRequestHtmlPage_ThenBodyContainsValueOfManipulatedInjectedObject() {
        // how is it possible to manipulate the injected object with value=MY_VALUE?
        assertEquals("MY_VALUE", getBodyValue());
    }

    private String getBodyValue() {
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/hfe/faces/label.xhtml");
        WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
        return body.getText();
    }

}
```

label.xhtml

```
<html>
<h:body>
    #{label.value}
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from the TomEE User MailingList: Using the Annotation @Specializes or using a ServletFilter. You can find the example code at the GitHub project.